# character count of textarea on dynamic character limit length, when click on checkbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

[image]I have a textrea and the character limit of that textarea is 620 by default.
I want to change the textarea character limit to 268, when clickon checkbox below the textarea. and it should also display the 620/used character, and also change to 268/used character.

I have change the character limit of the textarea fomr 620 to 268 dynamically when checkbox checked and when uncheck the checkbox again character limit will showing 620 it is working fine. But when I tried to fetch the value of textrea it is always taking 620, because of i have added for by default value.

**use for unicode allow in message**

```
        function myFunction(chk) {
        var targetElement = document.getElementById('totalchar');
        console.log(targetElement)
          if (chk.checked){
             targetElement.innerHTML= "268";
          }
          else{
            targetElement.innerHTML="620"
          }
        }
     //use for unicode allow in mesage end.


character count javascript
function counterUpdate(opt_countedTextBox, opt_countBody, opt_maxSize) 
        {

            var countedTextBox = opt_countedTextBox ? opt_countedTextBox : "counttxt";
            var countBody = opt_countBody ? opt_countBody : "countBody";
            var maxSize = opt_maxSize ? opt_maxSize : "totalchar";


            var field = document.getElementById(countedTextBox);

            if (field && field.value.length > maxSize) {
                    field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxSize);
                    alert("Sorry! You have reached your maximum message limit.")
            }
            var txtField = document.getElementById(countBody);
                    if (txtField) {  
                    txtField.innerHTML = field.value.length;
        }
     }
```

**HTML Code**

```
    <tr class="frmline">
        <td width="19%">Enter Message: </td>
        <td width="22%" colspan="2"><textarea name="txtmsg" id="txtmsg" dispname="Message" onkeyup="counterUpdate(&#39;txtmsg&#39;, &#39;countBody&#39;,&#39;620&#39;)" tagid="txtmsg" onfocusout="counterUpdate(&#39;txtmsg&#39;, &#39;countBody&#39;,&#39;620&#39;);NewLineCharFlag=true;" onblur="counterUpdate(&#39;txtmsg&#39;, &#39;countBody&#39;,&#39;620&#39;);NewLineCharFlag=true;" style="margin-right: 25px; width: 250px; height: 150px;resize:none;" onfocus="counterUpdate(&#39;txtmsg&#39;, &#39;countBody&#39;,&#39;620&#39;);NewLineCharFlag=false;" rows="10" validations="b" cols="20"></textarea> <span id="totalchar"></span>/<span id="countBody" class="counter1">0</span>*
        </td>
      </tr>
     <tr class="frmline">
        <td width="19%">Allow Unicode: </td>
        <td width="22%"><input type="checkbox" name="allowunicode" onchange="myFunction(this)" id="allowunicode" /></td>
        <td width="59%">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the fully answer and some help from @gopalyadav

**Here is my HTML code**

```
<tr class="frmline">
    <td width="19%">Enter Message: </td>
    <td width="22%" colspan="2"><textarea name="txtmsg" id="txtmsg" style="margin-right: 25px; width: 250px; height: 150px;resize:none;" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea> <span id="totalchar">620</span>/<span id="countBody">0</span>*
    </td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="frmline">
    <td width="19%">Allow Unicode: </td>
    <td width="22%"><input type="checkbox" name="allowunicode"  id="allowunicode" /></td>
    <td width="59%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
```

**Here is my Javascript code**

```
var countedTextBox = document.getElementById("counttxt");
        var check1 = document.getElementById('allowunicode');
        var limitVal = document.getElementById('totalchar');
        var textArea1 = document.getElementById('txtmsg');
        var charEntered = document.getElementById('countBody');


        check1.addEventListener('click', () => {
          if (check1.checked) {
            limitVal.innerHTML = '268';
            checkMaxLimit(268);
          } else {
            limitVal.innerHTML = '620';
            checkMaxLimit(620);
          }
        });

        function checkMaxLimit(limit) {
          if (textArea1 && textArea1.value.length > limit) {
              textArea1.value = textArea1.value.substring(0, limit);
            alert('Sorry! You have reached your maximum message limit.');
          }

        }

        textArea1.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
          var chhhr = textArea1.value.length;
          checkMaxLimit(+limitVal.innerHTML);
          if (chhhr.value >= limitVal) {
            //alert('Maximum value reached');
            charEntered.innerHTML = limitVal.innerHTML;
          }else{
          charEntered.innerHTML = textArea1.value.length;
          }

    });
```

Find the working demo link : https://codepen.io/ajitk34/pen/qejgGG

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<textarea id="textarea1">

</textarea>
<br>
<p>Text limit is : <span id="text-limit">620</span></p>
<p>Character entered: <span id="charEntered"></span></p>

<input type="checkbox" id="check1"/>
```

Javascript

```
const check1 = document.getElementById('check1');
const limitVal = document.getElementById('text-limit');
const textArea1 = document.getElementById('textarea1');
const charEntered = document.getElementById('charEntered');

check1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (check1.checked) {
    limitVal.innerHTML = '268';
    checkMaxLimit(268);
  } else {
    limitVal.innerHTML = '620';
    checkMaxLimit(620);
  }
});

function checkMaxLimit(limit) {
  if (textArea1.value.length > limit) {
    alert('Maximum value reached');
    textArea1.value = textArea1.value.slice(0, limit);
  }
}

textArea1.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  charEntered.innerHTML = textArea1.value.length;
  checkMaxLimit(+limitVal.innerHTML);

});
```

Or you can check the stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vxhkpe

I have not covered the corner cases in my code and not handled the cosmetic stuff like to show * symbol if max length breaches :)

Comment: Its works for me but when character count cross the limit, it should auto erase the extra character. for now it is not working.

Comment: You can use slice to shorten the text area value.

Comment: Updated the answer and stackblitz demo, check once.

Comment: It is working but the character entered count is mismatch. when you add more than the limit character.

Comment: I already said in my answer that I didn't cover corner cases. I hope you can resolve it on your own.